# document.ready inside body tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web app that has a universal HTML header include, so I'd like to put page-specific scripts in each page instead of having it load for everything. I tried putting `document.ready()` near the end of the `<body>` of a page and it seems to be working fine. Are there any potential hazards to putting it there instead of inside the `<head>`?

Comment: Refer this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659121/where-to-place-document-readyfunction

Answer (score 8):

Yahoo recommends putting all scripts at the end of your document for performance - http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

Comment: I guess I could even put it between </body> and </html>?

Comment: Best not - there's not supposed to be anything in html other than head and body-or-frameset. A browser might choose not to execute the code; in any case it certainly wouldn't validate.

Answer (score 3):

None. Just make sure everything is loaded in the proper order.