# Where to place $(document).ready(function()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

We often read here and there, that we must place our js code either on the page head section or *before* (sorry) the end body tag. Discussions about this aside, I'm just looking to know what are the reading order for such things by the browsers (taking that they do act as equals here):

Can we place:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

No matter where on the page structure, because we are using `$(document).ready` or should we still place it on the head section ?

Can anyone please clarify this.

If my question isn't clear, I can rephrase.

Comment: Since the function isn't executed until the entire page is loaded and ready, it doesn't really matter. There may be a small performance difference.

Comment: If you put it at the end of the `<body>`, you won't need the `$(document).ready(function () {` part because the DOM will be ready

Comment: So, nobody has mentioned that there is one restriction: It needs to be after the jquery script reference, no?

Comment: "End of the body" does not mean _after_ the `</body>` tag... it means just _before_ it.

Comment: @collapsar: How is it that "end of the body" means *after* the `</body>` tag, but "end of the head" means *before* the `</head>` tag?

Comment: @CrazyTrain: you're right, i stand corrected

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can place **a** script anywhere in the document. Best practice usually advises placing scripts in the footer for page load performance concerns. Further, best practice usually advises placing the scripts together for ease of maintenance.

However, per the spec, there is no restriction on where in the document you place a `script` tag. You may place them together in the header, at the bottom of the body, sprinkled all over the document, or any combination thereof.

The use of the jQuery construct `$(document).ready` has the same result regardless of where it is placed within the document. The key is to understand the functionality behind this construct:

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received.

So, `ready` is similar to `document.onload`, but not the same. It doesn't matter where the code is, if you execute it when `document.onload` is fired or when jQuery fires `ready`. Code's placement in a document is only significant if it is NOT wrapped by some event handler/listener.

The only restriction on the location on `$(document).ready` is that it cannot happen before you include the jQuery library. `$(document).ready` is using jQuery, so if jQuery doesn't exist.... you can't use it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            alert('executed as soon as it is reached (as the document is downloaded)');
            $(document).ready(function () { alert('on jQuery ready'); });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="alert('executed on document.onload event');">
        <script>
            alert('executed as soon as it is reached (as the document is downloaded)');
            $(document).ready(function () { alert('on jQuery ready'); });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Documentation**

- SCRIPT specification at W3 - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html
- script (html 5) specification at W3 - http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html
- *Placing Javascript in your pages* at quirksmode - http://www.quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html
- Jquery `ready` - http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, `$(document).ready` event gets raised after DOM is completely loaded  so it doesn't matter where you place it.

But they say to write the script at end of the body because page will show up to the end user instantly and javascript will continue to run as background process.

Comment: You're right, rectified.

Comment: downvote revoked, comment deleted

Answer (score 1):

The browser executes the script from the top to the bottom, so the srcipt in the head section will execute before the script in the body. I prefer to put the script undernith the html code, but generally it desn't matter much if you vait for the page to fuly load.

Answer (score 0):

The document ready function will wait until the DOM is loaded before running. So technically it doesn't matter where you put it. Many people like putting script in the head, because it makes sure the script is read before the page is loaded. Other people like putting it at the very end (just before the end body tag) so that all of the elements of the page are loaded before the script reads them. But since you're waiting for the DOM to load anyway, it doesn't matter.

If you have a small function, then I would just put the document ready function in the head tags.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, the BKM is to place it in the footer (although mostly developers tend to place it in the head tag).
Main reason - most of the document DOM is rendered to the browser prior to loading JS.